# RIA services client code generation not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a problem with solution building. I can compile the solution without a problem when running msbuild from command line. However, when I compile throught Build Solution in Visual Studio I get a compilation error. The problem is with Ria Services Client code not fully generated when build is issued from VS.

When I compile just the project, which is bound to Ria Service, everything works fine.

I get a lot of warnings like these (when compiling from command line):

```
Assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2c5c654d367bf4a7' could not be loaded and will be ignored.
```

Do you have any suggestions on how to make Visual Studio build the solution?

Comment: which error do you get ? just in case, remember that you can attach a debugger to visual studio and see if it helps in getting a meaningful error

Comment: I don't get an error during generation unfortunately. It fails when compiling a project that uses services, because some classes are not generated in web.gs.cs file. They do get generated when I compile from command line though.

Comment: Really strange. I'd open another instance of VS, attach the debugger to the VS instance, make sure that the second instance will break on *any* CLR exception and try to compile the project. When the code generation run it should throw some sort of exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with concurrent compilation of projects. Changing build order has helped with this.